# cannot construct std::string from placeholder in Boost.Spirit

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I have started working on a Boost.Spirit based simple parser that will parse a C++-like file (the only C++-ish part is the built-in template types; e.g. `map<string, smart_ptr<int>> name_object_map;` - but this is built-in the compiler, and user cannot declare template classes). Nevertheless, the grammar is intended to contain data structure declarations, and not expressions, except the constant expressions that are used for initialization of enumerator declarations; `enum E { a = 4 * 5 + 3 };` is valid. This is not currently a problem for me, because I couldn't parse `E` the way I want yet :)

I have made the following yesterday, after reading the docs and examples, but it doesn't compile:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_char_class.hpp>
#include <cassert>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

struct context {};

class foo {
  std::string name;
  const context *ctx;

public:
  foo(const std::string &name, const context *ctx) : name(name), ctx(ctx) {}
};

using foo_ref = std::shared_ptr<foo>;

template <typename Iterator>
struct skipper : boost::spirit::qi::grammar<Iterator> {
  skipper() : skipper::base_type(start) {
    using namespace boost::spirit;
    qi::char_type char_;
    ascii::space_type space;

    start = space                             // tab/space/cr/lf
            | "/*" >> *(char_ - "*/") >> "*/" // C-style comments
        ;
  }

  boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator> start;
};

template <typename Iterator>
struct the_parser : boost::spirit::qi::grammar<Iterator, std::vector<foo_ref>(),
                                               skipper<Iterator>> {
  the_parser() : the_parser::base_type(start), current_context(&root) {
    using namespace boost::spirit;
    namespace phx = boost::phoenix;

    identifier = qi::lexeme[qi::alpha >> *qi::alnum];
    start = *(foo_decl); // currently, no semantic action attached.
                         // This will create the root decl in ast.

    foo_decl = (lit("foo") >> identifier)[qi::_val = std::make_shared<foo>(
                                               qi::_1, current_context)] >>
               qi::char_('{') >> qi::char_('}') >> qi::char_(';');
    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((identifier)(start)(foo_decl));
  }
  boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), skipper<Iterator>>
      identifier;
  boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<foo_ref>(), skipper<Iterator>>
      start;
  boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, foo_ref(), skipper<Iterator>> foo_decl;
  context root;
  const context *current_context;
};

int main() {
  the_parser<std::string::const_iterator> parser;
  std::vector<foo_ref> root;

  const std::string content = "foo john_doe { };";
  auto first = content.cbegin(), last = content.cend();
  bool r = boost::spirit::qi::phrase_parse(
      first, last, parser, skipper<std::string::const_iterator>(), root);
  assert(r && first == last);
}
```

Compiling this with clang on Mac (the first line is `std::make_shared`):

```
error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'foo'
          __second_(_VSTD::forward<_Args2>(_VSTD::get<_I2>(__second_args))...)
          ^         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
...
note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'const boost::phoenix::actor<boost::spirit::argument<0> >' to 'const std::string' (aka
  'const basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >') for 1st argument
  foo(const std::string &name, const context *ctx) : name(name), ctx(ctx) {}
  ^
```

In `foo_decl`s semantic action, it cannot construct a `foo` (through `std::make_shared`), because the first attribute's result cannot be converted to `std::string`. However, if I add a class member `std::string s`, and do this instead, it works:

```
foo_decl = (lit("foo") >> identifier)[boost::phoenix::ref(s) = qi::_1] >>
                 qi::char_('{') >> qi::char_('}') >> qi::char_(';');
```

Likewise, if I try to `std::cout` it, I can see `john_doe` is printed.

If I bind a member function call with phoenix, it also works:

```
foo_decl = (lit("foo") >> identifier)[qi::_val =
                   boost::phoenix::bind(&the_parser, this, qi::_1)] >>
           qi::char_('{') >> qi::char_('}') >> qi::char_(';');

foo_ref make_foo(const std::string &n) {
  return std::make_shared(n, current_context);
}
```

These last three workarounds mean that there is an implicit conversion sequence from `decltype(qi::_1)` to `std::string`; isn't this correct?

I would be very happy, if you could show me my mistake or the gap in my understanding of how semantic actions, and placeholders work. It looks very strange to me as to why `std::make_shared` doesn't work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all:

- I'd steer cleer from smart pointers in Spirit

  - [making a vector of shared pointers from Spirit Qi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30763212/making-a-vector-of-shared-pointers-from-spirit-qi/30764109)
  - [How can I use polymorphic attributes with boost::spirit::qi parsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23299722/how-can-i-use-polymorphic-attributes-with-boostspiritqi-parsers/23301519)
- I'd steer away  from semantic actions if you don't need them (you don't) [Boost Spirit: "Semantic actions are evil"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259440/boost-spirit-semantic-actions-are-evil)
- the problem is with the placeholder: you can't use it statically, you need to use it in a lazy expression (Phoenix Actor)

Using the phoenix::function from the first link:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c69eaa18dd6a6f40)</kbd>**

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <cassert>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

namespace {
    template <typename T> struct make_shared_f {
        template <typename... A> struct result { typedef std::shared_ptr<T> type; };

        template <typename... A> typename result<A...>::type operator()(A &&... a) const {
            return std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<A>(a)...);
        }
    };

    template <typename T> using make_shared_ = boost::phoenix::function<make_shared_f<T> >;
}

struct context {};

class foo {
    std::string name;
    const context *ctx;

  public:
    foo(const std::string &name, const context *ctx) : name(name), ctx(ctx) {}
};

using foo_ref = std::shared_ptr<foo>;

template <typename Iterator> struct skipper : boost::spirit::qi::grammar<Iterator> {
    skipper() : skipper::base_type(start) {
        using namespace boost::spirit;
        qi::char_type char_;
        ascii::space_type space;

        start = space                             // tab/space/cr/lf
                | "/*" >> *(char_ - "*/") >> "*/" // C-style comments
            ;
    }

    boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator> start;
};

template <typename Iterator>
struct the_parser : boost::spirit::qi::grammar<Iterator, std::vector<foo_ref>(), skipper<Iterator> > {
    the_parser() : the_parser::base_type(start), current_context(&root) {
        using namespace boost::spirit;
        namespace phx = boost::phoenix;

        identifier = qi::alpha >> *qi::alnum;
        // This will create the root decl in ast.

        foo_decl = ("foo" >> identifier) [qi::_val = make_shared_<foo>{}(qi::_1, current_context)] >>
                   '{' >> '}' >> ';';

        start      = *foo_decl; // currently, no semantic action attached.
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((identifier)(start)(foo_decl));
    }
    boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> identifier;
    boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, foo_ref(), skipper<Iterator> > foo_decl;
    boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<foo_ref>(), skipper<Iterator> > start;
    context root;
    const context *current_context;
};

int main() {
    the_parser<std::string::const_iterator> parser;
    std::vector<foo_ref> root;

    const std::string content = "foo johndoe { };";
    auto first = content.cbegin(), last = content.cend();
    bool r = boost::spirit::qi::phrase_parse(first, last, parser, skipper<std::string::const_iterator>(), root);
    if (r)
        std::cout << "success\n";
    else
        std::cout << "failed\n";

    if (first != last)
        std::cout << "remaining unparsed: '" << std::string(first,last) << "'\n";

}
```

Prints

```
success
```

Along with the debug output of

```
<start>
  <try>foo johndoe { };</try>
  <foo_decl>
    <try>foo johndoe { };</try>
    <identifier>
      <try>johndoe { };</try>
      <success> { };</success>
      <attributes>[[j, o, h, n, d, o, e]]</attributes>
    </identifier>
    <success></success>
    <attributes>[0x60600000ebb0]</attributes>
  </foo_decl>
  <foo_decl>
    <try></try>
    <fail/>
  </foo_decl>
  <success></success>
  <attributes>[[0x60600000ebb0]]</attributes>
</start>
```

Comment: I'll be back later to look at your specific example.

Comment: Thank you! I think I can live without `shared_ptr`, but I didn't understand how I can do without semantic actions. After parsing identifier, how can I construct a `foo_decl` with the matched identifier?

Comment: I've updated the demo with your specific sample in mind: [Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c69eaa18dd6a6f40). W.r.t. the "parent context" pointers, it would seem you just want to build a recursive AST tree. I have at least a few dozen examples of that around on [SO] but I don't see what you need it for given your grammar.

Comment: Thanks for the live demo. I'll search SO for your examples, and in particular a solution that _doesn't use_ semantic actions. `parent_context` corresponds to declarative region of the name. So, in `struct S { enum E { a }; E e; };`, `struct S` is the parent context of `E`, much like C++.

Comment: That's fine, but your sample doesn't parse anything like that :) Make your AST simply recursive (look through my answers for examples) and separate your _runtime_ context from parsing, $0.05