# Boost Spirit eliminate left recursion from simple addition operator

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I am trying to use boost spirit to create a parser for a simple language. The first statement I am trying to parse is a simple numeric addition: "3.14 + 1". It segfaults, and my research indicates it is because of a left-recursive implementation, but I can't wrap my head around the solution for this that isn't left-recursive. Here is my parser implementation:

```
template<typename Iterator>
struct simple_grammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, AstNodePtr(), ascii::space_type> {

  simple_grammar() : simple_grammar::base_type(start) {
    using qi::double_;
    using qi::_1;
    using qi::_2;
    using qi::_3;

    auto addhelper = '+' >> expression;
    auto add = expression >> addhelper;

    expression = add[qi::_val = make_shared_<AddNode>()(_1, _2)]
               | double_[qi::_val = make_shared_<DoubleNode>()(_1)];

    start = expression;
  }


  qi::rule<Iterator, AstNodePtr(), ascii::space_type> start;
  qi::rule<Iterator, AstNodePtr(), ascii::space_type> expression;
};
```

AstNodePtr is a typedef for a std::shared_ptr to an AstNodeBase class, from which DoubleNode and AddNode inherit. I didn't include those definitions just to keep the post short, but can if requested. It is pretty self-explanatory I think, the idea is to compose an AST. The make_shared_ implementation comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21516201/how-to-create-boost-phoenix-make-shared).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of things about your example.

First off, you use `auto` with Spirit Qi expressions. That's not valid, and leads to UB:

- [Assigning parsers to auto variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22023779/assigning-parsers-to-auto-variables/22027181#22027181)
- also [boost spirit qi parser failed in release and pass in debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34281509/boost-spirit-qi-parser-failed-in-release-and-pass-in-debug/34283062#34283062)
- [undefined behaviour somewhere in boost::spirit::qi::phrase_parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26410498/undefined-behaviour-somewhere-in-boostspiritqiphrase-parse/26411266#26411266)
- [boost spirit V2 qi bug associated with optimization level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20763665/boost-spirit-v2-qi-bug-associated-with-optimization-level/20766909#20766909_)

Next off, you chose to use polymorphic Ast nodes. That's possible but likely not efficient:

- [How can I use polymorphic attributes with boost::spirit::qi parsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23299722/how-can-i-use-polymorphic-attributes-with-boostspiritqi-parsers/23301519#23301519)
- [Semantic actions runs multiple times in boost::spirit parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37911950/semantic-actions-runs-multiple-times-in-boostspirit-parsing/37912787#37912787)
- but also [making a vector of shared pointers from Spirit Qi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30763212/making-a-vector-of-shared-pointers-from-spirit-qi/30764109#30764109) which you may have found

Finally, there's the left recursion, since your expression starts with itself, leading to infinite recursion. The only way to solve it is to split your productions up into "levels" of expressions. This also aids in generating the desired operator precedence:

```
 expression = term >> char_("-+") >> term;
 term = factor >> char_("*/%") >> factor;
 factor = simple >> char_("^") >> simple;
```

In your case, I'd suggest:

```
    simple
        = qi::double_
            [_val = make_shared_<DoubleNode>()(_1)]; 
        ;

    expression 
        = (simple >> '+' >> expression)
            [_val = make_shared_<AddNode>()(_1, _2)]
        | simple
        ;
```

Of course, you can be simpler and slightly less inefficient here:

```
    expression 
        = simple [_val = _1] 
        >> *(('+' >> expression)
                [_val = make_shared_<AddNode>()(_val, _0)])
        ;
```

### Full Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6bd6a20912ed15e4)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

namespace { // https://stackoverflow.com/a/21565350/85371

    template <typename T>
    struct make_shared_f
    {
        template <typename... A> struct result 
            { typedef std::shared_ptr<T> type; };

        template <typename... A>
        typename result<A...>::type operator()(A&&... a) const {
            return std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<A>(a)...);
        }
    };
}

template <typename T>
using make_shared_ = boost::phoenix::function<make_shared_f<T> >;

struct AstNode {
    virtual ~AstNode() = default;
};
using AstNodePtr = std::shared_ptr<AstNode>;
struct DoubleNode : AstNode {
    DoubleNode(double) {}
};
struct AddNode : AstNode {
    AddNode(AstNodePtr, AstNodePtr) {}
};

#include <iomanip>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

template<typename Iterator>
struct simple_grammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, AstNodePtr()> {

    simple_grammar() : simple_grammar::base_type(start) {
        using namespace qi::labels;

        simple
            = qi::double_
                [_val = make_shared_<DoubleNode>()(_1)]; 
            ;

        expression 
            = simple [_val = _1] 
            >> *(('+' >> expression)
                    [_val = make_shared_<AddNode>()(_val, _1)])
            ;

        start = qi::skip(qi::space) [ expression ];
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((start)(expression)(simple))
    }
  private:
    qi::rule<Iterator, AstNodePtr()> start;
    qi::rule<Iterator, AstNodePtr(), qi::space_type> expression;
    // implicit lexemes
    qi::rule<Iterator, AstNodePtr()> simple;
};

int main() {
    simple_grammar<std::string::const_iterator> g;

    for (std::string const input : {
            "1 + 2",
            "3.14"
            })
    {
        auto f = begin(input), l = end(input);
        AstNodePtr ast;
        if (qi::parse(f, l, g, ast)) {
            std::cout << "Succeeded: " << boost::core::demangle(typeid(*ast).name()) << "\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "Failed\n";
        }

        if (f!=l)
            std::cout << "Remaining unparsed " << std::quoted(std::string(f,l)) << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Succeeded: AddNode
Succeeded: DoubleNode
```

Comment: Off-topic: For a good case study where complete C++ compatible operator precedence and associativity is reached (without too much ast/rule overhead) see my recent [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210289/discussion-between-sehe-and-llm) at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60845800/how-to-combine-skipping-and-non-skipping-lexeme-rules/60846101#60846101). It **does** show how you can have awesome polymorphic ASTs without _dynamic_ polymorphism

Comment: Extended the example with support for `-+*/%^` with proper precedence (as well as parenthesized subexpressions and unary `-+`). Still using the polymorphic Ast for instructional purposes: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7a053d937aef0ba7

Comment: Wow that is fantastic, thank you! I am required to use a polymorphic AST as this is for an OO class (the AST is really the purpose, not the parsing mechanism). But, doesn't this solution implicate that only things that can reduce to simple can be on the left side of an operator? Also, I took the bad advice about using auto for the nested rules from here: http://pastexen.com/code.php?file=uYv1RjUJZt.cpp&raw

Comment: Thought of this as a potentially more elegant way to compose the Ast nodes: [using a generator type (`X`)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/68c5d6995d8116f5). No more phoenix business with shared-pointers. All overloads in `X` are "normal C++".